# django orm .values() is not working in for loop

Tags: django, orm

```
menu_group = MenuGroup.objects.filter(is_deleted=False,store_id=store_id,version=version).values('id','name','color')
menu_group_serializer = MenuGroupMixSerializer(menu_group, many=True)
for menu_group_data in menu_group_serializer.data:
    menu_item_group = MenuItemGroup.objects.filter(menu_group_id=menu_group_id, is_deleted=False).values('id','name','starting_price','menu_group')
```

`.values()` in second for loop is not working the **menu_group** is foreign key

Comment: it's giving me AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'pk'

Comment: likely `color` is a `ForeignKey` as well? Looks like it is the serializer...

Comment: Hey, please also share your models in the question, so people can better figure our what the problem is.